# Is there a way in which a string array variable can be used as an index in another 2D array in JAVA?

Tags: java

I have declared a `string array d={monday,tuesday,wednesday}` in JAVA.I want to use `"d"` as an index in another 2D array `e[d][t]`,such that when I do `d++`, Monday becomes Tuesday.....Is this possible?If so, how?

Comment: an array index has to be an int. Not sure what you are asking...

Comment: I think you should rethink your design. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Be clear on what you want first. The syntax for declaring array is vague. Are you new to Java?

Comment: If you are looking for pointer arithmetic in Java, you can't.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are looking for

```
List<String> indexes = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, String> map=  new HashMap<String, String>();
//iterate through each keys
for(String index: indexes){
  String value  = map.get(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was C++, you could've possible overriden the `++` operator to increment an element in an array, but not possible in Java (as per my first view).

Still searching, keep the thread open.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should better use hashmaps to get the design more clear. A possible solution could be as follows.

```
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Map<Integer, String> map=  new HashMap<Integer, String>();

Integer i= 0;

while(some condition){

   String str= map.get(i++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you could use an enum

```
public enum FOO
{
monday(0),tuesday(1),...;
private int index;
private FOO(int index){ this.index = index; }
public int getIndex(){ return index; }
}
```

that way, you'll be able to do

```
FOO d = FOO.monday;
some_array[d.getIndex()][some_index];
```

and you can also implement some kind of function getNext(), that get you the next day in your enum.

Answer (score 0):

This enumerated map is the best way represent your string values with meaningful numerical order. I would still use a hash map implementation with this however. It would look something like

```
HashMap<Weekday, ArrayList> = ...
```

Then you can still easily loop through all the days of the week to get your values.

Caution though. You aren't specific on what kind of values these days are accessing. Presumably more strings. what are your trying to represent, or accomplish?